# asp.net form authentication ticket slidingExpiration code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, formsauthenticationticket

I want to be able to detect when the form authentication ticket updates due to the slidingExpiration flag being set to true. I need to call a backend service with the new expiration time. Does anyone know where the code is that re-validates the ticket and updates it with the new expiration time due to the slidingExpiration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to detect when the form authentication ticket
>   updates due to the slidingExpiration flag being set to true

This happens on any HTTP request that the user sends to your site.

Comment: Do you know where the class and function is that makes this happen so I can override it?

Comment: @metalideath, yes, this happens inside the `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticate` method.

Comment: Hmm it does not look like you can override this class. Is there some way to run some code when the form auth ticket it updated?

Comment: No, it only happens on requests with less than half of the authentication time left.